# BizTalk message context property: datetime when message was published to message box

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations

In my project I have an orchestration that subscribes to messages in messagebox.
Is there any way in orchestration to determine the time when message was received by the message box?

I know such property `Microsoft.BizTalk.Operations.BizTalkMessage.CreationTime`, but maybe there is a corresponded context property for that purpose? I don't want to use .net code and connect to messagebox database through .net api.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, no.  There is no system Context Property for Message create/publish time.  What you see is in the database, but nowhere on the Message.

My recommendation would be a custom Pipeline Component that sets a Custom Property with a time stamp.

Custom Pipeline Components: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa548050.aspx

Pipeline Component Wizard: http://btsplcw.codeplex.com/